# Seagate Crystal Reports 8.0 on windows server 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2008-r2

The report is not loading on my asp page. Connection to DB is correct no errors where thrown. I used to install my app in a win server 2003 sp2 but now I migrated to win server 2008 sp2 and the reports are not showing anymore. Any ideas or links on how to install seagate crystal reports 8 on win server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

So you have an application that uses Crystal Reports, and these do not run on Win Server 2008 SP2? What happens when you try to install CR8 onto the server?

Version 8 is a very old version of Crystal Reports - probably dating from the later 1990's - but it will usually run on much newer operating systems if the Runtime components are installed.

You could try installing a slightly later version of the Runtime from here:
http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+Report+Designer+Component+Runtime+Distribution+-+Versions+pre+8.0.x+to+12.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to register **ntwdblib.dll** inside your **system32** or **syswow64** (if 64 bit).